# Creating an Action

Tags: node.js, graphql, hasura

I am creating my first Hasura Action and got stuck.

While I do think there team have done great job in documentation, I am having tough time in comprehending few things.

First, what is this `!`? in say this  `login (username: String!, password: String!): LoginResponse`

Second, Suppose this is my typeconfiguration

```
input validateDriverTlcNumberInput {
  driverName: String!
  tlcNumber: Boolean!
}

type validateDriverTlcNumberOutput {
  valid: Boolean!
  message:String!
}
```

if `valid` is true then there would be no `message` but if `valid` is false, then there would be message explaining what went wrong?

How should I define my output?

Answer (score 1):

[In graphql all types are nullable, adding `!` makes a type non-null](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Type-System.Non-Null) that being said you can define the output type as this so the message can be nullable

```
type validateDriverTlcNumberOutput {
  valid: Boolean!
  message:String
}
```